# How can I create an ExpandableListView programmatically?

Tags: android

I am trying to create a ExpandableListView programatically, but so far it reserves space for it, but the space is completely black! Nothing shows.
I do have some special requirements here:

1. I want to do everything on code, no XML. So far my entire UI has zero XML and I would like to keep it that way
2. I want to derive my activity from Activity if possible. I find it silly to change the class just because ExpandableListView would like that. And what if other controls also want wierd activity special classes? Hopefully it is possible to have an ExpandableListView on an Activity, right?

So here is my code so far for the adapter:

```
// -------------------------------------------
// DoubleStringArrayExpandableListAdapter
// -------------------------------------------
public class DoubleStringArrayExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
public ArrayList<String> Parents = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> Children = new ArrayList<String>();
public Activity mContext;

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
  return Children.get(groupPosition);
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
  return childPosition;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
  return 1;
}

public TextView getGenericView()
{
  AbsListView.LayoutParams lp = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

  TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
  textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
  // Center the text vertically
  textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
  // Set the text starting position
  textView.setPadding(55, 0, 0, 0);
  return textView;
}

public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
  TextView textView = getGenericView();
  textView.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
  return textView;
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return Parents.get(groupPosition);
}

public int getGroupCount()
{
    return Parents.size();
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent)
{
  TextView textView = getGenericView();
  textView.setText(getGroup(groupPosition).toString());
  return textView;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return true;
}

public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return true;
}
}
```

And here is my code for creating the ExpandableListView:

```
listNews = new ExpandableListView(this);
adapterNews = new DoubleStringArrayExpandableListAdapter();
adapterNews.mContext = this;
listNews.setAdapter(adapterNews);
listNews.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
listNews.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
//listNews.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
//listNews.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  
listNews.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200/*doesnt workLayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT*/));
lLayout.addView(listNews);
adapterNews.Parents.add("Parent");
adapterNews.Children.add("Child");
```

Any ideas why it doesn't work and what is wrong here??? thanks a lot =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter since you added the data in last two lines of code or you can call setAdapter after the last line of your code.